# How to create custom color picker in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, colors

How can I create a color picker in OS X with Objective-C?

Do you have some piece of code that works?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way to use [NSColorWell](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nscolorwell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you want something different, look on GitHub and [CocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com):

- [MKPopoverColorWell](https://github.com/mkdynamic/MKPopoverColorWell)
- [BFColorPickerPopover](https://github.com/DrummerB/BFColorPickerPopover)

...and probably many more.